# LinkedList insert using head insert

Tags: java, linked-list

Ok the issue I have now is that I am getting an error at 'public class MagazineView extends Applet {' I get that "the blank field Jlist may not have been initialized"

Here is my  GUI applet

```
public class MagazineView extends Applet {
Button button, button2;
final MagazineList Jlist;


public void init() {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//NORTH PANEL
JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JLabel label = new JLabel("Add Magazine:     ");
final JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
JButton button = new JButton("List Magazines");


button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final String name=text1.getText();
            Magazine mag = new Magazine(name);
            Jlist.insert(mag);
        }

});

    topPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    topPanel.add(text1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    topPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
   //CENTER PANEL
     JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
     JTextArea atext = new JTextArea();
     centerPanel.add(atext, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //BOTTOM PANEL  
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Delete All:     ");
    JTextField text2 = new JTextField();
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Delete Magazine");
    bottomPanel.add(label2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    bottomPanel.add(text2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    bottomPanel.add(button2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    northPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    northPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    northPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //Frame
    frame.add(northPanel);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

   }


}
```

And here is my Methods

```
      public class MagazineList {
      private MagazineNode list;

      public MagazineList(){
           list=null;
      }
      public void insert (Magazine mag){
    MagazineNode node = new MagazineNode(mag);
    node.next = list;
    list = node;
  }
      public void add (Magazine mag){
           MagazineNode node = new MagazineNode (mag);
           MagazineNode current;

           if(list==null)
                list = node;
           else
           {
                current = list;
                while(current.next !=null)
                     current = current.next;
                current.next = node;
            }
    }

    public void DeleteNode(Magazine mag)
    {
        if(list == null) throw new RuntimeException("Cannot delete, Empty List");

        if( list.magazine.equals(mag) )
        {
            list = list.next;
            return;
        }

        MagazineNode cur  = list;
        MagazineNode prev = null;

        while(cur != null && !cur.magazine.equals(mag) )
        {
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur.next;
        }

        if(cur == null) throw new RuntimeException("Cannot delete, not in list");

        //delete cur node
        prev.next = cur.next;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result ="";

        MagazineNode current = list;

        while (current !=null){
            result += current.magazine + "\n";
            current = current.next;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private class MagazineNode {
        public Magazine magazine;
        public MagazineNode next;

        public MagazineNode(Magazine mag){
            magazine = mag;
            next = null;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's the issue?  What behaviour are you seeing that you should not see?  What have you tried?  What's the specific error message or behaviour?  We can't help you without something to go on.

Comment: Please Post your exact error message  or write the exact problem .

Comment: There is no error. I just don't know what code to write in the public void Insert(Magazine mag){
    list = new MagazineNode(mag);}
To make the node insert the new string;
Or how to pass the method at 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if (e.getSource() == button) {
         final String name=text1.getText();
         
    
   }

Comment: Please remove the bulk if your code, which is irrelevant to the question. See [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inserting nodes at the head, you don't need to traverse the list.  Your `list` variable is the head of the linked list, so have your new node point to it and make it the head.

```
/**
 * Add a new node containing the input Magazine to the front of the linked list.
 *
 * @param mag A magazine to put at the head of the list.
 */
public void add (Magazine mag){
    MagazineNode node = new MagazineNode(mag);
    node.next = list;
    list = node;
}
```

You might want to change the name `list` to `head`. Notice that this didn't need any `if` statements.  By the way,you don't have to show the GUI code.